# Primary key with two references

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I would like that my relation table "In" has a Foreign key SSN which references to two tables, but the SSN is only in one of these two tables.
When I do this:

```
ALTER TABLE "In"
ADD CONSTRAINT in_C1 FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES patient(SSN),
ADD CONSTRAINT in_C2 FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES patientWithDoD(SSN)
```

Then the SSN must be in the table patient and patientWithDoD. The SSN should be in one of the two tables, but not both. How can I do this?

Comment: Foreign key values are required to be present in all tables referenced; that is the  core reason for their existence. NULL can be used to make the reference optional, but any "real" value must be present. _...and generally, having one field reference more than one table is not a very good idea._

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: If this is MySQL, why do I see postgres tag on your question???  Please remove.

Comment: A followup question that occurs to me: What is so different about patients "withDoD" that necessitates a separate table? Have you considered having just one `patient` table, and a separate `patientDoDInfo` table that references the `patient` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a column has a non-null value all related foreign key constraints are checked and validated. If the check fails, the row cannot be inserted or updated.

If you have two FKs and you want only one of them to be enforced, then you'll need to:

- create two separated nullable columns, one for each FK, and
- add a `CHECK` constraint to enforce one and only one is not null.

For example:

```
create table "In" (
  id int primary key not null,
  ssn int, -- nullable
  ssn_dod int, -- nullable
  constraint fk1 foreign key (ssn) references patient (ssn),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (ssn_dod) references patientwithdod (ssn),
  constraint chk1 check (ssn is null and ssn_dod is not null or
                         ssn is not null and ssn_dod is null)
);
```

Unfortunately, MySQL just recently started to enforce the `CHECK` constraints (MySQL 8.0.3 if I remember well). If you are using an older version of MySQL, you are out of luck: MySQL will allow you to write the constraint and save it, but won't enforce it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't have a SSN attribute on patientWithDoD table. To reference a foreign key you have to add this attribute to this table.

You recommend you, add only necessary attributes to the patient table. For ex: ssn, name, surname etc.

Then don't add name, surname and other patient attributes to patientWithDod table. You can use only ssn to refer remaining patient data. So add foreign key that ssn refers to Patient.ssn

This structure would be better and you don't have to refer patienWithDod table.